# How to display google map of location (Ex: Atlanta, GA) chosen by user on previous page

Tags: javascript, google-maps

See below sample of simple google map set to Lat and Long. 
This code would work for the purpose, but need php echo of City, State chosen by user to display in lieu of Lat Long. Can anyone outline the code to make this execute?
Want to be compatible with Google Maps API v3. Greatly appreciate.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <style type="text/css">
      html { height: 100% }
      body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
      #map_canvas { height: 100% }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript"

      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&sensor=SET_TO_TRUE_OR_FALSE">
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
          zoom: 8,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
            mapOptions);
      }
    </script>

  </head>
  <body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

In past, i've used the following code to display City, State:

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;sensor=true&amp;key=BQIAAAAmGS6pKWpRUcdw4oR9pzpvBQzjcAJnzRmzqULnEw6fdi4mPoYnxR1kxeM4lTW9o75OG9vfiUP8DKkig" type="text/javascript"></script>    
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var map = null;
    var geocoder = null;
    function initialize() {
      if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
        map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
        map.setMapType(G_HYBRID_MAP);
        disableDefaultUI: true;
        map.enableScrollWheelZoom();
        geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();
      }
        showAddress("<?php echo $_SESSION['city_name']; ?>");
    }
    function showAddress(address) {
      if (geocoder) {
        geocoder.getLatLng(
          address,
          function(point) {
            if (!point) {
            //alert(address + " not found");
            } else {
            map.setCenter(point, 13);
            map.setZoom(13);
            }
          }
        );
      }
    }
</script>

</head>

<body onload="initialize()" onunload="GUnload()">
```

Comment: Google has great documentation, what exactly doesn't work? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/

Comment: Google does have great documentation, but none specific to the top code sample displaying city, state chosen by user on previous page of website. Can you help?

Comment: My first google search result is : http://tech.cibul.net/geocode-with-google-maps-api-v3/

Comment: Thank you for search link. After review, it is not specific to the question. User selects city, state on previous page of website. The city, state is inserted in code through php to display the selected location on map. Should be common code, but no specific examples. In past, I was able to accomplish this task with the 2nd code example above, but is not going to work with Google Maps API v3. Can you see how to make this work?

Comment: There is exactly what you are looking for. COPY / PASTE ;-)

Comment: You have been a great help with this question. Thank you.

Comment: Map is showing the php inserted city, state. However, map loads the LatLong coordinate map first, then opens the city, state php echo. How to open city, state only? Any insight? I'm blinded by details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code was copied from [geocode-with-google-maps-api-v3](http://tech.cibul.net/geocode-with-google-maps-api-v3/) and reorganized so it should look like your old code.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <style type="text/css">
        html { height: 100% }
        body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
        #map_canvas { height: 100% }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_KEY&sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var geocoder;
        var map;
        var marker;

        function initialize() {
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 8,
                center: latlng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
            geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                draggable: true
            });

            showAddress('Ljubljana');
        }

        function showAddress(address) {
            geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function(results, status) {
                if (status != google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    return;
                }
                if (results.length > 1) {
                    alert('Multiple addresses found; showing first one ...');
                }
                $.each(results, function(i, item) {
                    var location = new google.maps.LatLng(item.geometry.location.lat(), item.geometry.location.lng());
                    marker.setPosition(location);
                    map.setCenter(location);
                    return false;
                });
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your help with this was great. The map is now showing City, State. However, it loads the LatLong location first, then opens city, state.

Comment: Not seeing how to eliminate the initial load of LatLong map?

Comment: Why don't you just hardcore lat and lng, and don't use getcode... ?

Comment: Would that initialize to the showAddress (city, state). Don't understand. Your help is greatly appreciated?

Comment: You asked how to change v2 to v3 for your code. This is v3 version of your code. If you upgrades/changes ask other answer.

Comment: I've accepted your answer. Thanks again...greatly appreciated.